# Get scroll event for ScrollViewer on Windows Phone

Tags: events, windows-phone-7, scroll, scrollviewer, windows-phone

Question:
Get scroll event for ScrollViewer on Windows Phone

I have a scrollviewer like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScroller">
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- ... -->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I need the event for when the scrolling occurs for MyScroller:

```
// MyScroller.Scroll += // <-- "Scroll" event does not exist on ScrollViewer
MyScroller.MouseWheel += MyScroller_MouseWheel; // Does not fire on scroll
MyScroller.ManipulationDelta += MyScroller_ManipulationDelta; // Fires for pinch-zoom only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that simple, but there's a few scroll detection mechanisms written in this question:

[WP7 Auto Grow ListBox upon reaching the last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456563/wp7-auto-grow-listbox-upon-reaching-the-last-item)

Basically take a look at the way OnListVerticalOffsetChanged is called and used.

Comment: Thanks, this goes a lot further for what I need. I hope it works without the Listbox, however, because I have had perf issues using Listboxes with images and my custom layout

Comment: If you are using something other than a ListBox - e.g.a ScrollViewer and an ItemsControl with a StackPanel, then be careful with how much memory your app uses to render the UI - you may need to use VirtualisingStackPanel in order to avoid excessive memory use.

Answer (score 12):

MouseMove fires when ScrollViewer is scrolled:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyScroller.MouseMove += MyScroller_MouseMove;
}

void MyScroller_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();// This will fire
}
```

It isn't intuitive, since it is named as a "mouse" event and there is no mouse on the phone. The touch point does move, however, relative to the ScrollViewer container, which is how it can handle scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

With Mango, you can watch for the "ScrollStates" visual state to change as described in this [sample project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx).