# Scroll event for Windows Phone ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

In my Windows Phone 8 application I am trying to implement a custom control that behaves like the built-in calendar control which displays the current date above the scrollable content (daily views). Initially I have tried to use the LongListSelector control (which gives me the hierarchical view), but I am not able to determine the scroll position and therefore cannot update the header (the date in the case of the calendar control).

So I switched to using a ScrollViewer control which contains a StackPanel with different controls inside.

Whenever the user scrolls the content I would like to be notified so I can update the UI relative to the content being shown. However, the ScrollViewer doesn't have any explicit scrolling events.

I have tried to use the LayoutUpdated event (which seems to get called frequently enough for my purposes), but when I then update the UI in the event handler another LayoutUpdated event is raised and an infinite loop is created.

How can I update the UI based on the scroll position?

Comment: Look at `IScrollInfo` and implement it in a custom panel wrapping StackPanel or others.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, But check this links, this may help.

[Get scroll event for ScrollViewer on Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264772/get-scroll-event-for-scrollviewer-on-windows-phone)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/b1cdf697-ed37-4d3a-9f3c-46338bdc92b4/how-to-get-a-scroll-event-from-a-scrollviewer?forum=silverlightbugs