# C# Windows Phone 7 ListBox Scrolling Up / Down event?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am looking for a way to know when a user is scrolling the listbox on my Windows Phone 7 application up or down.

The closest I can come to is:

```
    private double fDown = 0.6;

    private void buddyList_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sView = e.ManipulationContainer as ScrollViewer;

        double lBox = 25 - fDown;

        double nBox = 25 - sView.VerticalOffset;

        if (nBox > lBox)
            MessageBox.Show("up!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("down!");
    }
```

However, that doesn't work correctly. I need to know when it's at the bottom of the listbox compared to scrolling through the middle of it.

When it's at the bottom of the listbox I want to enable a timer to keep it at the bottom constantly. Or is there another way to keep it at the bottom constantly...? Is there anyway I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to a friend and he gave me this as an answer (to anyone who looks in the futue):

```
        var sView = e.ManipulationContainer as ScrollViewer;

        double lBox = 25 - sView.ScrollableHeight;

        double nBox = 25 - sView.VerticalOffset;

        if (lBox < nBox)
            //Listbox Scrolled Up
        else
            //Listbox at Bottom
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `LongListPicker` from the windows phone 7 toolkit. These have events available for scrolling. See [this guide here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/WPToolkitBook)

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456563/wp7-auto-grow-listbox-upon-reaching-the-last-item) then you should find everything you need to implement this (the [ScrollViewerMonitor](http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx) from Matt Lacey's answer is what I use).