# Listbox detecting scrolling down or up

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to deteck when listbox is scrolling down or up, then I will show or hide menu. How can What can help me do this, can I use any event or?

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248171/detect-scrolling-event-of-listbox) helps.

Comment: have a look at this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082559/c-sharp-windows-phone-7-listbox-scrolling-up-down-event

Comment: Could just subscribe to a property change in the VerticalOffSet